# An example of unbounded Lesbegue integrable function $f(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

Can you give me an example of unbounded Lebesgue integrable function $f(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$? Thank you.

Comment: You've been here for a year and posted $93$ question before this one. You should know that posing a question like this gets a bad reception (as well as the *other* closed questions you've asked...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $1/\lvert x \rvert^{1/2}$ on $[-1,1]$ and extend it by 0 outside there.

Comment: But what's f(0)?

Comment: Define it to be anything you want there; $\{ 0 \}$ is a set of measure zero so it doesn't matter for the sake of integration.

Comment: But how to show it's Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: Use elementary calculus.

Comment: But like $lnx$ is not Lebesgue integrable on (0,1)

Comment: Why isn't $\ln(x)$ Lebesgue integrable? I believe it is.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f(x) =x$ on the rationals, $f(x)=0$ on the irrationals.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a function that takes the value $n$ in a small enough neighborhood interval $I_n$ of $n$, and such that the neighborhoods $I_n$ are disjoint. Then $$\int_\Bbb R f d\lambda =\sum n\mu(I_n)$$ and you can decide what "small enough" means. For example, taking $\mu(I_n)<1/n^3$ works.

Answer (score 0):

It may be cheating a little, but $f(x)=0$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=\infty$.